# Unable to select menu item in selenium

Tags: html, selenium

```
<div id="alis-menu" location="alis-menu" style=""> 
<div id="menu/menuBar_35" class="v-menubar v-menubar-spml-menubar spml-menubar" tabindex="0" style="width: 794px;">
 <span class="v-menubar-menuitem v-menubar-menuitem-selected"> <span class="v-menubar-submenu-indicator">►</span>
 <span class="v-menubar-menuitem-caption">Client</span> </span>
```

This is my code and I am unable to select menu item from this. I have tried `Byid`, `ByclassName` still no luck.

My code is:

```
WebElement Menu = ieDriver.findElement(By.className("v-menubar-menuitem v-menubar-menuitem-selected"));
WebElement root = Menu.findElement(By.linkText("Client"));
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: did you try `Xpath`

Comment: try with this xpath - "//span[@contains(text(),'Client')]"

Comment: @PranayKumar What do you mean by `unable to select menu item from this` ? What is the error you see? At which line? Consider updating your manual steps and your work as well. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB: I have used:   ieDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ieDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    WebElement element = ieDriver.findElement(By.id("user.name"));
          element.sendKeys("Clerk");
          WebElement element1 = ieDriver.findElement(By.id("user.password"));
          element1.sendKeys("a");
          ieDriver.findElements(By.id("login.button")).get(0).click();
          WebElement Menu = ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath( "//span[@v-menubar-menuitem-caption(text(),'Client')]"));

Comment: @DebanjanB
where my webcode is:
<div id="alis-menu" location="alis-menu" style="">
<div id="menu/menuBar_35" class="v-menubar v-menubar-spml-menubar spml-menubar" tabindex="0" style="width: 794px;">
<span class="v-menubar-menuitem">
<span class="v-menubar-submenu-indicator">►</span>
<span class="v-menubar-menuitem-caption">Client</span>
</span>
I am not getting error, only the Client field is not getting selected.

Answer (score 0):

i see there are two classnames in the byclassname method,  I suggest that you can remove one name and see if the result is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select an element that has multiple classes, instead of selecting by className you should select it by cssSelector and adding all the classes separated by a `.`  Because I don't know what language you are using I can assume that your code will work with this modification, if not please refer to the documentation for selecting by css selector for your programming language used:

```
WebElement Menu = ieDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("v-menubar-menuitem.v-menubar-menuitem-selected"));
```

And for the second select you should select by xpath with containing text:

```
WebElement root = Menu.findElement(By.xpath( "//span[@contains(text(),'Client')]"));
```

And again, I'm not sure about the syntax, but the logic is ok.